# What is the time complexity of this code? in python

Tags: python, time, complexity-theory

```
def func(n):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(n):
        if i % 3 == 0:
            for j in range(n / 2):
                sum += j
        elif i % 2 == 0:
            for j in range(5):
                sum += j
        else:
            for j in range(n):
                sum += j
    return sum
```

I understand that the first for statement repeats n times. but
The number of iterations varies depending on the if statement. How do I calculate the time complexity?

I looked for a lot of data, but most of them were simply double for loop time complexity.

Comment: Have you check this out? https://pypi.org/project/big-O-calculator/

Comment: Try to think about how many times each of the inner loops are executed, relative to n.

Comment: This code can be replaced with a single formula, reducing it to O(1). Are you sure complexity of this exact code is important?

Comment: O(n^2) i would say...

Comment: O(n^2) in your case :) Since that's how you big-O notation works.